# How to get the topic of the kafka message using CreatDirectStream?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using spark-streaming with Kafk and I am trying to get the topic of a Kafka Message using this approach:

```
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder, Tuple2[String, String]](ssc, kafkaParams, topics, (mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String, String]) => { (msg.topic, msg.message)})
```

But the Intellij cannot import the kafka.message.MessageAndMetada. I could not find this import. How do I get the topic? Is there an other way to get it?

The objective for this is handle messages from each topic in a different way, so I need to know the topic for each message.

Answer (score 0):

You can find class `kafka.message.MessageAndMetada` inside [kafka library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.11/0.8.2.1) which is provided by [spark-streaming-kafka](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11/2.0.1), so it looks like you are missing this dependency.

Comment: I am using the spark integration with kafka version 0.10 and spark 1.6. I think this library does not have the class. I cannot use yours because it use spark 2.0 and did not find the same library with spark 1.6.